# From point A to point B, can only move up and right, how many possible movements?

Tags: algorithm

A friend of mine has had a programming test yesterday. He passed the test anyway, but I'm curious about the answer.

Here is the test, supposed you are on point A and need to go to point B. You can only move up and right. How many possible movements do you have?

The options he remembered were 16, 64, 3125.

What is the answer and how to explain that?

[image]

Comment: related :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3929268/674039

Comment: What have you tried? BTW, you can easily ignore all odd answers since each solution has a pair where you switch all UPs with RIGHTs and vice versa.

Comment: You have to choose a path consisting of 8 moves, 4 "right" and 4 "up", the answer is the binomial coefficent (8,4) and it equals 70. This has nothing to do with programming by the way :/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a math problem, not a programming one.

Comment: @Mat, If I understand the algorithm, I might be able to create the code to make a simple simulation...

Comment: Yes, and? Your question isn't about code, it's pure math. You're better off with that sort of question on a math site. If you've got problems implementing the algorithm, that's a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the commentators that this question has nothing to do with programming.  It can be solved fairly easily with a simple recursive function:

```
def n_ways(x, y):
    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        # we are on the "edge", there is only one way to get there
        return 1
    else:
        # the number of ways to get here equals the sum of the number of 
        # ways to get to the point directly below and the number of ways 
        # to get to the point directly left
        return n_ways(x-1, y) + n_ways(x, y-1)
```

Let's try it out.  Point B is x position 4, y position 4.

```
>>> n_ways(x=4, y=4)
70
```

We can also use our algorithm to generate the diagram below:

```
>>> for y in reversed(range(5)):
...     for x in range(5):
...         n = n_ways(x, y)
...         print str(n).rjust(2),
...     print
...     
 1  5 15 35 70
 1  4 10 20 35
 1  3  6 10 15
 1  2  3  4  5
 1  1  1  1  1
```

As Stéphane Laurent has already mentioned, you can easily find Pascal's Triangle hiding in this algorithm!  :)

[image]

Comment: so the parameters we supply to x and y are 4?

Comment: Rather (unless you consider `B` has coordinates `(0,0)`?), there's only one path when `x=4 or y=4`, but that does not change the result.

Comment: this is fantastic, it fits the @StéphaneLaurent concept about binomial coefficient, for x = 0 and y = 0, we get 1, for x = 1, y = 1, we get 2, for x = 2 and y = 2, we get 6, probably my brain can't process x = 4 and y = 4 if I draw it manually, thanks, much appreciate

Comment: Oh ok, you consider paths going from B to A, equivalently.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I should have mentioned the coordinate system I chose.  Point A corresponds to `x=y=0` and point B corresponds to `x=y=4`.  It makes no difference whether you consider the x axis horizontal or vertical, because the problem is symmetric.

Comment: @wim, Sure, but if you go from A to B, there's not only one path when x=0 or y=0. Going to B from A fits your rationale.

Answer (score 3):

Rotate your picture. Your problem consists in finding the number of paths from a particular vertex in the [Pascal graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle) to the root vertex. Labelling the vertices at level n by the integers 0, 1, ..., n, then the number of paths from vertex k at level n is the binomial coefficient "n choose k". In your case this is vertex k=4 at level n=8, and "n choose k"=70.

[image]